# Table with Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Table that shall contain some columns with basic facts on the left and on the right side there shall be some columns that can be tabbed. Something like this:

[image]

So the Question is, how to do this?

I could personaly think of two solutions, but I actually don't like both:

- Write a own Table for Tab1,Tab2 ... That contains the basic data and the Tabbed Data
- Write a Table for the basic Data and one for each Tab. Here I think you would have a lot of Design problem "glueing" both tables together, so they look like one table.

So actually I don't like both solutions. Maybe there is a better solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could give the columns that belong to each tab their own unique class, e.g. `.tab1-columns`, `.tab2-columns`, etc. Then, you could show or hide the column depending on the active tab. The tabs, however, would exist outside of the table. Alternatively, you could pt the tabs into a pseudo- header row above the actual table header row, with the first header cell spanning those cells that shouldn't be "tabbed". However, I believe leaving the tabs outside of the table would be a bit more semantic in nature.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you. this really is a solution I hadn't thought of. But it sounds way better than my ideas.

Comment: NP, glad I could help. :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I implemented it. And works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Render all columns but hide them (`display: none;`) except the column by default.

Then add an `click` event on the tabs to switch the visible columns. be sure to use just the [nav-tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs) and not the [js component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).. it will be easier I think